# Why does Matthew think that no one else realizing Steven’s two drinks was lucky?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-killing-of-a-sacred-deer

In *The Killing of a Sacred Deer (2017)*, Matthew tells Anna about how he anesthetized Steven:

> Matthew: You know an anesthesiologist is never to blame for the bad
>   outcome of an operation. The surgeon is always responsible. He'd had
>   two drinks  that morning before we went in to prepare. Luckily no one
>   else realized. I was the only one that knew.

Why does Matthew think that no one else realizing Steven’s two drinks was lucky?

Comment: because they are friends and he wouldn't tell on him?

Answer (score 1):

Murphy and the anesthetist are close friends. They don't appear close considering their opening conversation, but that applies to all characters in the movie - they are a little lifeless or distant.

Had anyone other than the anesthetist noticed Murphy was going into an operation drunk, he would have lost his license. He is "lucky" because only the anesthetist knew and didn't tell on Murphy. This is why Murphy continues to have a job and his fancy life.